# How can we insert multiple keys into a registry folder without using 3rd party tools?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-command-prompt

To insert multiple keys into a registry folder (e.g. `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\....\....`), I basically have to manually right click → <kbd>N</kbd>ew → <kbd>K</kbd>ey for each key.

[image]

This can get annoying and redundant, especially at times when I need to insert more than 10 keys.

Is there a way to insert multiple keys into a registry folder using the default GUI?

Is there a cmd command to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using built in tools on Windows you have a few options.

1. Use the `regedit` GUI.

Microsoft `regedit` provides [import and export](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755091.aspx) [export visible in your screenshot] options.  When you export a key, it will appear in a .REG file. This is an example.

example.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Example]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Example\keyA]
"value0"=dword:00000000
"value1"="data"
```

To import open `regedit`, use the menu and navigate File -> Import, then select the .REG file.

2. Use the `reg` command line utility.

The `reg` utility also provides [import](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742021.aspx) and [export](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742017.aspx) options.  To perform the same steps as above, you would do something like.

```
:: Export
REG EXPORT HKCU\SOFTWARE\example\ example.reg

:: Import
REG IMPORT example.reg
```

You can also write keys/values/data ad-hoc with `reg`.

```
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\example\keyA" /v "value0" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\example\keyA" /v "value1" /t REG_SZ /d "data" /f
```

3. Use a Group Policy Registry Preference item.

Use `gpmc.msc` to configure a [Group Policy Registry Preference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753092.aspx) and deploy it as needed.

[image: gpp registry item]

Comment: You can also script it as `regedit /s filename.reg` if you need to.  (And also what jscott said.)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to jscott's response, [powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315270.aspx) can natively manage the registry.

Comment: Not avail on server 2003 and many other systems.

Comment: Not *natively* on server 2003 true, but after July this year it will be on every supported version of windows.

Comment: You'll need to clarify what you mean by that. Do you mean **every** from the very first version of Windows?

Comment: @Pacerier [Support for Windows Server 2003 ends July 14, 2015](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-server-2003/). After which all _supported_ versions of Windows will also have PowerShell.

Comment: @jscott, Ah, [semantics](http://superuser.com/q/758307/78897).......

Comment: Powershell 2.0 can also be installed on Windows 2003 and XP.

Comment: Seriously? A powershell reference w/ no code? -1, _code or it didn't happen._

Comment: @BigHomie - Thanks, i will endeavour to copy the contents of a linked website into my answer rather than merely link to it next time.

Comment: Andy, even if this *is* a link to technet, a link only answer is bad for several reasons here.