# Distributing Registry Changes - Make registry changes on systems across the network

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have some workstations (workstation1, workstation2, workstation3) connected to a domain (MyDomain).
I would like to create a script that changes to each workstation the key:

```
HKLM \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Control \ terminalserver \ AllowRemoteRPC
```

and set it from 0 to 1.
Can you give me any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds familiar: http://serverfault.com/questions/681996/how-can-we-insert-multiple-keys-into-a-registry-folder-without-using-3rd-party-t

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group Policy Preferences targeted at the computer would be the most "user friendly" way to make this change.

Assuming that all these computers are in the same Organizational Unit (OU) in your Directory, created a Group Policy Object (GPO) at that OU. In that GPO, under the "Computer Settings", "Preferences", "Windows Settings", and "Registry", create an entry that targets the key and value you'd like to set.

Microsoft has [step-by-step](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753092.aspx) directions here but, honestly, the interface is intuitive enough that you should be able to figure it out. If you're concerned about testing it create a "bogus" entry first on an OU with a single computer in it and observe the results using REGEDIT.

Answer (score 3):

Use [regedit and a .reg](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516) file to do this and deploy it using AD.

Comment: I finally gave in to Group Policy Preferences. As long as all the machines being managed are Windows XP (with the GPP update installed) or newer it's probably not worth the pain of deploying a registry merge and will be easier on the next admin who may not understand be as savvy.

Comment: I would too if I ever did any windows admin stuff but the OP wanted a script ... How're you anyway ?

Comment: @Iain - +1 for my reading comprehension, eh?   >smile<  Oh, you know-- busy as heck-- the glamorous life of an independent IT contractor combined with the life of having a 2 and 1/2 y/o child at home! It's very relaxing... heh heh...

Comment: Drop into slack some time and say Hi.